# c optarg atoi with no args

Tags: c, args, atoi

Consider the following code:

```
int number;

while((w = getopt(argc, argv, "n:s:")) != -1) {

        switch (w){

            case 'n': {

                opfile->filename = optarg;

            }break;

            case 's': {

                number = atoi(optarg);

            }break;

        }
}
```

Now, when I leave both options or the option `s` blank, for example I start my program with no command line args, then the `number` variable still gets a random value.

What am I missing here? Some if-statement in the case of `s`? Specifically, I want to cover the case where the user doesn't assign a specific value/option to `s` in the command line arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there is no 's' option passed to the program, the `case 's'` branch is not executed at all, and nothing else sets `number` to a value, which means that subsequent reads trigger undefined behavior.  (This is potentially *much worse* than just giving you a random value when you read from it later.  It's a must-fix bug.)

But because nothing else touches `number`, it will be enough to change

```
int number;
```

to

```
int number = 0;
```

or whatever else you want your default to be.

(By the way, you should really be using [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) instead of `atoi`, because `atoi` ignores syntax errors.)

Comment: +1 And, just a note to OP, the fact that it's only giving a random variable makes it hard to know a program could crash on other systems (or even eventually on the same system). UB can be a pain.